# HP ALM - Unable to post the attachment to a defect via python

Tags: python-2.7, pywin32, hp-alm

I get the error `you don't have the required permissions to execute this action`,
when I try to attach a file to the defect in HP-ALM.

code

```
bug.post()

attachfact=bug.Attachments;

attachObj = attachfact.AddItem(None)
attachObj.Description = "Failed Records"
attachObj.Filename = "LOGS\\"+test_case.Name+"_LOG.xlsx"
attachObj.Type=1

ExScoraqe - attachObj.AttachmentStorage
ExScoraqe.ClientPath - attachObj.Filename
ExStoraqe.Save(test_case.Name+"_LOG.xlsx",True)
attachObj.Post()

defect_ids = defect_ids + ” "+str(bug.Field("BG_BUG_ID"))
print "Defect ID : "+defect_ids
```

error
[image]

Comment: Hi, kindly please, provide your code as the text in the `code block` instead as the image, as well the error output, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you attach **those** files to **the** bug (from browser let's say)? Did you pass the authentication stage? Are you sure you're connecting to the right *ALM* instance? Did you install everything that it needs (e.g. some *COM* objs) on your machine? And **do** post the **text** copy / pasted from *cmd*, not the image.

Comment: Hi, i tried attaching manually.. and i was able to attach the file to the defect.. only when i try via the code it throws this error at the **Post()** line... What are those COM objs u r mentioning about??